# grep-ing multiple files

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to grep multiple files in a directory and collect the output of each grep in a separate file ..So if I grep 20 files, I should get 20 output-files which contain the searched item. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `for` statement:

```
for a in *.txt; do grep target $a >$a.out; done
```

Answer (score 2):

just one gawk command

```
gawk '/target/ {print $0 > FILENAME".out"}' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use just the shell, no need external commands

```
for file in *.txt
do
    while read -r line
    do
        case "$line" in 
            *pattern*) echo $line >> "${file%.txt}.out";;
        esac
    done  < "$file"
done
```

Comment: This would be slower than the other solutions as is opens the same output file again for each item found.